# Application crashes once after I call MAPIUninitialize api

Tags: memory-leaks, crash, exchange-server, mapi

So, I have been working with MAPI API's. In that Whenever I call the MAPIUninitialize api, my application crashes. on further debugging, I found that, IMAPISession::OpenMsgStore is the reason behind the crash, whenever the OpenMsgStore function is executed during the program runtime, my app crashes exactly after the MAPIUninitialize is triggered. which is similar to the discussion in this thread mentioned below, in which soln is not available.

https://peach.ease.lsoft.com/scripts/wa-PEACH.exe?A2=MAPI-L;e6f3847a.0801&S=

I have checked my program for memory leaks, and I'm sure there is none and also, if i comment that particular api, my program doesnt crash, i dont understand the reason for the crash. I have tried all possible alternatives. Can anyone help on this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your wonderful suggestions. I have fixed the issue, my application actually calls the mapi api's defined in a c++ dll from golang. Because of that, every mapi api defined as a DLL function had different thread ID, When I tied the DLL function calls to same thread using runtime.LockOSThread() / runtime.UnlockOSThread() , it started working, no more crashes.

Ref: https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#LockOSThread

Answer (score 0):

It mostly likely means you still have live MAPI objects. It is also possible that the sequence of MAPIInitialize / MAPIUninitialize is too quick and the common Office run-time is still (asynchronously) initializing when you attempt to shut it down.

Also, not all stores are created equal - IMAP4 is probably the worst.

Comment: Hi Dmitry, 

Thanks for the reply, As yu suggested, I tried adding a 1 min sleep before triggering the MAPIUninitialize call, and still it crashes, so that cannot be the reason, also w.r.t the live mapi objects, as i said earlier, my program crashes only because of this api, if it is commented, it doesn't crash. so if there is a possibility of handle/memory leak , it can be only because of that api, i'm very sure, that i have released the handle of the msgstore i got using the openmsgstore api using the release() function, still it seems to crash. any other suggestions ?

Comment: It is really impossible to say without seeing the source code.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear where and when these methods are used. Is it a secondary thread?

Anyway, here is what MSDN states:

> A client must also invoke MAPIInitialize on every thread before using any MAPI objects and MAPIUninitialize when that use is complete. These calls should be made even if the objects to be used are passed to the thread from an external source. MAPIInitialize and MAPIUninitialize can be called from anywhere except from within a Win32 DllMain function, a function that is invoked by the system when processes and threads are initialized and terminated, or upon calls to the LoadLibrary and FreeLibrary functions.

I'd suggest playing with the [MFCMAPI](https://github.com/stephenegriffin/mfcmapi) source code - you can run it under the debugger and see whether an issue is still reproducible or not.